# Ubuntu 18.04 - Wired connection drops (need turning off and on)

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet

Two weeks ago I installed **Ubuntu 18.04** for the first time. I have a wired internet connection there.

Most of the time, connection works good but sometimes, 2 or 3 times a day, I suddenly have no internet connection. I need to turn the wired connection **OFF** and then **ON** to fix this.

[image: enter code here]

Can't figure out where is the problem. The cable is OK and connection works on other devices in the network.

I have automatically installed drivers.

Do you know what can I do?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @KevinRED Unfortunately, no. I tried to reset network settings, there was some update too... It seems to be dropping less but there are problems...

Comment: Yes, I am experiencing the same issue too and searching for the cause and solution.